# Implementation of bit field in c

Tags: c, memory, bitwise-operators, bit, bit-fields

We have been given an assignment to create a made - up version of an assembler (not with the exact assembly commends)

We have been instructed to use memory efficiently (not in a big O notation type of memory efficiency, but rather efficient to use data structures)

Since each command is translated into 24 bit machine code, I figured that the most efficient way to store the command's machine code is using bit fields, So I implemented the following bit field:

**(in bit_field.c)**

```c
#include "bit_field.h"
int set_bit(bit_field *destination, int location, enum bit_values value)
{
    if(location >= BITS)
        return 0;
    if(value == ONE)
        (destination)[location / BITS_IN_BYTE] |= 1UL << location % BITS_IN_BYTE;
    else
        (destination)[location / BITS_IN_BYTE] &= ~(1UL << location % BITS_IN_BYTE);
    return 1;
}
enum bit_values get_bit(bit_field *destination, int location)
{
    return ((destination)[location / BITS_IN_BYTE] >> location % BITS_IN_BYTE) & 1U;
}
void init_bit_field(bit_field *new_bit_field)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < BITS; i++)
        set_bit(new_bit_field, i, ZERO);
}
void init_bit_field_by_str(bit_field *new_bit_field, char *string)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < BITS; i++)
        set_bit(new_bit_field, i, *string++ - '0');
}
```

**(in bit_field.h)**

```c
#define BITS 24
#define BITS_IN_BYTE 8
#define BYTES BITS / BITS_IN_BYTE
enum bit_values {ZERO = 0, ONE = 1}bit_values;
typedef unsigned char byte;
typedef byte bit_field [BYTES];
int set_bit(bit_field *, int , enum bit_values);
enum bit_values get_bit(bit_field *, int);
void init_bit_field(bit_field *);
void init_bit_field_by_str(bit_field *, char *);;
```

**(test at input.c)**

```c
#include "bit_field.h"
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    bit_field bits;
    init_bit_field(&bits);
    set_bit(&bits, 22, ONE);
    for(i = 0; i < BITS; i++)
        printf("%d, ", get_bit(&bits, i));
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile the following code (gcc C90) I get the following errors:

```
bit_field.c:14:53: error: invalid operands to binary >> (have ‘byte (*)[3] {aka unsigned char (*)[3]}’ and ‘int’)
     return ((&destination)[location / BITS_IN_BYTE] >> location % BITS_IN_BYTE) & 1U;
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^~
bit_field.c:15:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
avivgood@ubuntuVM:~/CLionProjects/Maman14$ gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic input.c bit_field.c bit_field.h -o example.out
bit_field.c: In function ‘set_bit’:
bit_field.c:7:49: error: invalid operands to binary | (have ‘byte (*)[3] {aka unsigned char (*)[3]}’ and ‘long unsigned int’)
         (&destination)[location / BITS_IN_BYTE] |= 1UL << location % BITS_IN_BYTE;
                                                 ^~
bit_field.c:9:49: error: invalid operands to binary & (have ‘byte (*)[3] {aka unsigned char (*)[3]}’ and ‘long unsigned int’)
         (&destination)[location / BITS_IN_BYTE] &= ~(1UL << location % BITS_IN_BYTE);
                                                 ^~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
bit_field.c: In function ‘get_bit’:
bit_field.c:14:53: error: invalid operands to binary >> (have ‘byte (*)[3] {aka unsigned char (*)[3]}’ and ‘int’)
     return ((&destination)[location / BITS_IN_BYTE] >> location % BITS_IN_BYTE) & 1U;
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^~
bit_field.c:15:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
```

The errors doesn't seem to make any sense. my method of setting and resting bit should work. So why does it generate so many errors?

Comment: 1. "errors doesn't seem to make any sense". It absolutely does make sense. It tells you very clearly that the function is defined to take an argument but you call it with no args. 2. . Header files are not supposed to be passed directly to the compiler. You include them in `.c` file and compile the  `.c`. 3. Missing `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: "bit_field bits = init_bit_field();" "too few arguments to function ‘init_bit_field’" and `void init_bit_field(bit_field *);`. What not make sense here? Your call don't match the signature of your function here.

Comment: @Eraklon This errors does make sence and I have fixed them. the errors that dosen't make sense are the error with the bitwise oprators

Comment: out of your problem when you define something like `#define BYTES BITS / BITS_IN_BYTE` use () else operator precedence can invalid what you expect in a formula, so `#define BYTES (BITS / BITS_IN_BYTE)`

Comment: @kaylum mayby even ```*destination[location / BITS_IN_BYTE]```?

Comment: Do you really have to be able to set each bit separately? For example, you could use 1 byte for the instruction and the other 2 for parameters or specialisations of that instruction. Even if the instructions had to be 10 bits you could just use a single `and` to extract the value. The generated machine code would also be easier (faster) to execute.

Comment: why `BITS_IN_BYTE` instead of the standard `CHAR_BIT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you define

```
typedef unsigned char byte;
typedef byte bit_field [BYTES];
```

So `bit_field` is an array which has `BYTES` elements. But, when you define the function, you use pointer to `bit_field`:

```
int set_bit(bit_field *, int , enum bit_values);
enum bit_values get_bit(bit_field *, int);
void init_bit_field(bit_field *);
void init_bit_field_by_str(bit_field *, char *);
```

It's reason why program raises the error with bit operator. When you use:

```
destination[location / BITS_IN_BYTE]
```

This has the type `unsigned char *`. This is why we have the error:

```
 invalid operands to binary
```

Thus, you can use just `bit_field` instead of `bit_field *` as the argument of the function. Then in the function do not use ampersand (`&`) as:

```
destination[location / BITS_IN_BYTE]
```

Comment: Why is it a problem? should I use a singed char? or should I use ```*destination``` instead of ```destination```?

Comment: But if I don't do it via a pointer the original array won't be updated

Comment: It's is an array, so it's will be updated well (like update an array `int` for example). I do not understand what you want to do in your code. So i just propose one example how to use the for this declaration.